# Is $\{\text{polynomials}\}\ni p\mapsto p'(S)\in B(\ell^{2})$ a bounded operator, where $S$ is the forward shift on $\ell^{2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, operator-theory, differential-operators

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the space of all polynomials endowed with the norm
$$\|p\|:=\sup_{|z|\leq1}|p(z)|=\sup_{|z|=1}|p(z)|.$$
Let $S$ be the forward shift operator on $\ell^{2}$, that is,
$$S(x_0,x_1,\ldots):=(0,x_0,x_1,\ldots).$$
For $p\in\mathcal{P}$, let $p'\in\mathcal{P}$ denote the (formal) derivative.

> Is the operator $$\mathcal{P}\ni p\mapsto p'(S)\in B(\ell^{2})$$ bounded?

If this is true, then the proof must rely on the structure of $S$. Namely, it is in general not true that $$\mathcal{P}\ni p\mapsto p'(A)\in B(H)$$ is bounded for arbitrary Hilbert spaces $H$ and operators $A\in B(H)$. For example, if $H=\mathbb{C}$ and $A=1$. Indeed, if $p_{n}=z^{n}$, then $|p_{n}'(1)|=n$ and $\|p_{n}\|=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Never mind - the polynomials $p_{n}=z^{n}$ can also be used to show that $p\mapsto p'(S)$ is unbounded: $\|p_{n}'(S)\|=n$ and $\|p_{n}\|=1$. I forgot that $S$ is an isometry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the spectral radius $r(A)$ of $A$ is greater or equal $1.$ Then the mapping $p\to p'(A)$ is unbounded. Indeed for $p(z)=z^n$ we have $$\|p'(A)\|=n\,\|A^{n-1}\|\ge n\,r(A^{n-1})=n\,r(A)^{n-1}\ge n$$ In particular the mapping is unbounded for the shift operator, whose spectral radius is equal $1.$

There are operators for which the mapping is bounded.
Let $A$ be a normal operator so that $r(A)<1.$ Then $p'(A)$ is a normal operator. Thus
$$\|p'(A)\|=\max_{z\in \sigma(A)}|p'(z)|\le \max_{|z|\le r(A)}|p'(z)|$$
By the Cauchy integral formula we have $$p'(z)={1\over 2\pi i}\int\limits_{|w|=1}{p(w)\over (w-z)^2}\,dw, \quad |z|\le r(A)$$ Hence
$$|p'(z)|\le (1-r(A))^{-2}\max_{|w|\le 1}|p(w)|$$
Thus we finally obtain $$\|p'(A)\|\le (1-r(A))^{-2}\max_{|w|\le 1}|p(w)|$$